# Generating new subsets individually

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, subset

I'm trying to design an algorithm which will generate all the subsets from a list of items {0,1,2,3...n-1} individually. What I mean by this is that rather than using an algorithm which generates all 2^n subsets and then prints each of them, I want my algorithm to just generate one subset. I need this algorithm to be constant time (ignoring the time to print), and it needs to be represented by a Boolean array (where true means an integer i is in the subset, and false means it is absent).

Does anyone have any ideas about where to start for this? I have generated subsets before, but never as Booleans, and never in constant time.

Comment: "I want my algorithm to just generate one subset" - the empty subset seems the best one for this purpose. Is there anything that prevents your algorithm to be that easy? If yes, what?

Comment: According to a now-deleted answer: **"Please do not post a response to this question until Friday, 12 December. It is a college exam question."**